# Trouble connecting to a google apps server via MailCore

Tags: ios, mailcore

I'm trying to connect to Google Apps email server via IMAP. The code I am using below, every time I try to connect I get the error: `Parse error` Anyone know the source of this error?

```
    int port = 993;
    CTCoreAccount *account = [[CTCoreAccount alloc] init];
    BOOL success = [account  connectToServer:@"imap.gmail.com"
                                        port:port
                              connectionType:CTConnectionTypeStartTLS
                                    authType:CTImapAuthTypePlain
                                       login:login
                                    password:password];
    NSLog(@"Port: %d",port);
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Connection failed, error: %@",[account.lastError localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Connection succeeded");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues simultaneously going on here. The first was that my network had a firewall and that was the source of the `Parse Error`.

Second, when you need to connect to Google Maps IMAP server, you'll need to use the `CTConnectionTypeTLS` instead of `CTConnectionTypeStartTLS`, because the second one makes the server go bonkers.